# close popup window on script execution end

Tags: javascript

I have a php page to create an excel file and save it to a folder. I start from a page where user click on a button to start the script. My goal is to perform the following steps:

1. run the script in another window (I am now using a small popup);
2. when the script ends close the popup and in the main window display an alert to say that execution is ok;
3. on alert close refresh the file list displayed in the main window.

I know how to do all these stuffs but one: **how can i trigger any event (popup close and alert) when in the popup the script ends?**

My actual code for the popup is the following:

```
$('#elabora').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#data_rif').val();
    if (data=='') {
        $("#spnmsg").fadeTo(200,0.1,function(){
            $(this).removeClass().addClass('spn_error').html("Inserisci una data di riferimento per l'elaborazione").fadeTo(900,1);
        });
    }else{
        window.open('sofferenze/trxls.php?data='+data, "popupWindow", "width=10,height=10");
//here is where I want to trigger that when trxls.php ends the alert should be displayed.
    }
});
```

The script (beginning and end only)

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_sqlite3;
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod);
// Create a new PHPExcel object 
$ea = new PHPExcel();
...

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($ea, 'Excel2007');
ob_end_clean();
//$objWriter->save('php://output');
$objWriter->save('trackrecord/'.$data.'_trackrecord.xlsx"');
exit();
echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with `onbeforeunload`?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    // ...
}
```

**Edit:** Just add this event to your opened window like this:

```
$('#elabora').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#data_rif').val();
    if (data=='') {
        $("#spnmsg").fadeTo(200,0.1,function(){
            $(this).removeClass().addClass('spn_error').html("Inserisci una data di riferimento per l'elaborazione").fadeTo(900,1);
        });
    }else{
        var wndRef = window.open('sofferenze/trxls.php?data='+data, "popupWindow", "width=10,height=10");
        wndRef.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
              // Show your alert
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit:** You can close the window from your script. In fact browser doesn't allow to close the current opened window. You should call the close function from the caller but here is a little trick to close it anyway, use this function:

```
function close_popupWindow() {
    window.self.opener = window.self;
    window.self.close();
}
```

Comment: on the main page I am not firing onbeforeunload. Can you elaborate on this poin?

Comment: @LelioFaieta Can't you just close the window when your script ends?

Comment: it's a php script that builds an excel file and save it to a folder on the server. I have tried to close it by a script but doesn't do the trick

Comment: See the edited question. Added the script I run. The window.close call doesn't work

Comment: @LelioFaieta I added a little code that show how to close a window

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something in the new window when the script ends, use onbeforeunload as Ludvoic suggests.

If, on the other hand, you want to do something in the parent page after the child page is done running its script, that is a different story. You imply this in the question and therefore will answer this scenario.

You can use `localstorage` provided that both pages are served from the same domain. When the script is done running, the child page can update a value. The parent page can listen to the `storage` event to know when that happens. Here is a post discussing how to share data across tabs:

[Javascript; communication between tabs/windows with same origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236828/javascript-communication-between-tabs-windows-with-same-origin/12514384#12514384)

In the parent page:

```
$('#elabora').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#data_rif').val();
    if (data=='') {
        $("#spnmsg").fadeTo(200,0.1,function(){
            $(this).removeClass().addClass('spn_error').html("Inserisci una data di riferimento per l'elaborazione").fadeTo(900,1);
        });
    }else{
        localStorage.popup_script_done = false;
        window.open('sofferenze/trxls.php?data='+data, "popupWindow", "width=10,height=10");
    }
});

$(window).bind('storage', function (e) {
    if (localStorage.popup_script_done == true) {
        // Do stuff
    }
 });
```

In the popup:

```
// Do stuff
localStorage.popup_script_done = true;
```